# Удалить атрибут "muted" с тега "video"

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html5

Всем привет! Снова нужна ваша помощь, решил одну проблему, появилась вторая(

Нужно чтобы при клике на видео (когда переходит в полноэкранный режим) включался звук. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать ?

```js
$('video').on('click', function () {
    this.requestFullscreen();
})
$("body").on("mouseover", "video", function () {
    this.play();
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
});
$("body").on("mouseleave", "video", function () {
    this.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video muted>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решить проблему можно добавив `this.muted = false`:

`$('video').on('click', function () {
    this.requestFullscreen();
    this.muted = false;
})`

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!